# Google Maps - How to hide coordinates marker

Tags: javascript, maps

I am using a embed google maps iframe code.
But it´s appearing 2 markers.

One for the company and another one for the coordinates.
How can I hide the green coordinate marker?

```
<iframe width="600" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.es/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=es&amp;geocode=&amp;q=36.510085,-4.888811&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/diegomenezes/VYRmr/

Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

I think the green marker is referring to 'Near Places', I do not know if there's way to remove, but you can focus on your company including the parameter '&iwloc=A' if you want to

```
<iframe width="600" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.es/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=es&amp;geocode=&amp;q=36.510085,-4.888811&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;output=embed&amp;iwloc=A"></iframe>
```